# Python regular expressions assigning to named groups

Tags: python, regex, variables, variable-assignment

When you use variables (is that the correct word?) in python regular expressions like this: "blah (?P\w+)" ("value" would be the variable), how could you make the variable's value be the text after "blah " to the end of the line or to a certain character not paying any attention to the actual content of the variable. For example, this is pseudo-code for what I want:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile("say (?P<value>continue_until_text_after_assignment_is_recognized) endsay")
>>> m = p.match("say Hello hi yo endsay")
>>> m.group('value')
'Hello hi yo'
```

Note: The title is probably not understandable. That is because I didn't know how to say it. Sorry if I caused any confusion.

Comment: I fixed up your title a bit, but I think it was clear from your code example what you wanted (at least, I hope I interpreted it right).

Comment: FYI, the stuff between the parentheses is called a "group".  In your example 'value' is a name.  So, you are matching a "named group".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For that you'd want a regular expression of

```
"say (?P<value>.+) endsay"
```

The period matches any character, and the plus sign indicates that that should be repeated one or more times... so `.+` means any sequence of one or more characters. When you put `endsay` at the end, the regular expression engine will make sure that whatever it matches does in fact end with that string.

Answer (score 10):

You need to specify what you want to match if the text is, for example,

```
say hello there and endsay but some more endsay
```

If you want to match the whole `hello there and endsay but some more` substring, @David's answer is correct.  Otherwise, to match just `hello there and`, the pattern needs to be:

```
say (?P<value>.+?) endsay
```

with a question mark after the plus sign to make it *non-greedy* (by default it's *greedy*, gobbling up all it possibly can while allowing an overall match; *non-greedy* means it gobbles as **little** as possible, again while allowing an overall match).

Comment: I thought about that but given the OP's talk about matching to the end of the line, it seemed like a greedy operator would be appropriate.  Still, +1.